# Named annotation failing in jar and source

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

having a problem with the openkad project, but may be a guice/environment issue:

gist is code uses Guice to :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("openkad.rnd") 
Random provideRandom(@Named("openkad.seed") final long seed) {
        return seed == 0 ? new Random() : new Random(seed);
    }
```

however @Singleton and @Named("openkad.rnd") are both flagged by the compiler as incorrect placement.

and apparently correctly so, as the named annotation targets a field, not method:

```
/**
 * Annotates named things.
 *
 * @author crazybob@google.com (Bob Lee)
 */
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface Named {
  String value();
}
```

To recreate:

1. Create Java Project in eclipse using JDK 1.6 or 1.8 targeting various runtimes
2. Include dependencies via pom (guice 1 through 4 tried)
3. Using source or openkad r60 jar file run unit tests (https://code.google.com/p/openkad/)

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

Success for all UT's, but I see this instead:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.BootstrapNodesSaver.<init>(BootstrapNodesSaver.java:26):
 Binding to java.io.File annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.file.nodes) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

2) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.IncomingContentHandler.<init>(IncomingContentHandler.java:43):
 Binding to java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.executors.client) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

3) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.KadNet.<init>(KadNet.java:75):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Node annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.local.node) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

4) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.bucket.KadBuckets.<init>(KadBuckets.java:58):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.KeyFactory not found. No bindings to that type were found.

5) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.handlers.ForwardHandler.<init>(ForwardHandler.java:96):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Node annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.local.node) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

6) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.handlers.KademliaFindNodeHandler.<init>(KademliaFindNodeHandler.java:50):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Node annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.local.node) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

7) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.handlers.PingHandler.<init>(PingHandler.java:38):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Node annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.local.node) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

8) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.msg.ContentMessage.<init>(ContentMessage.java:26):
 Binding to long annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.rnd.id) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

9) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.msg.ContentRequest.<init>(ContentRequest.java:27):
 Binding to long annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.rnd.id) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

10) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.msg.FindNodeRequest.<init>(FindNodeRequest.java:25):
 Binding to long annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.rnd.id) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

11) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.msg.ForwardRequest.<init>(ForwardRequest.java:30):
 Binding to long annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.rnd.id) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

12) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.msg.PingRequest.<init>(PingRequest.java:22):
 Binding to long annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.rnd.id) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

13) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.net.KadServer.<init>(KadServer.java:59):
 Binding to com.google.inject.Provider<java.net.DatagramSocket> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.net.udp.sock) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

14) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.net.KadServer.<init>(KadServer.java:59):
 Binding to java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<java.net.DatagramPacket> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.net.buffer) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

15) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.net.MessageDispatcher.<init>(MessageDispatcher.java:56):
 Binding to java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue<il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.net.MessageDispatcher<?>> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.net.req_queue) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

16) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.op.EagerColorFindValueOperation.<init>(EagerColorFindValueOperation.java:73):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Node annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.local.node) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

17) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.op.JoinOperation.<init>(JoinOperation.java:48):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Key annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.keys.zerokey) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

18) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.op.KadFindNodeOperation.<init>(KadFindNodeOperation.java:49):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Node annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.local.node) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

19) Error at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.openkad.op.KadLocalCacheFindValueOperation.<init>(KadLocalCacheFindValueOperation.java:65):
 Binding to il.technion.ewolf.kbr.Node annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=openkad.local.node) not found. No bindings to that type were found.

19 error[s]
    at com.google.inject.BinderImpl.createInjector(BinderImpl.java:277)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:43)
    at il.technion.ewolf.kbr.KeybasedRoutingTest.the2NodesShouldAbleToSendArbitrarySerializableMessages(KeybasedRoutingTest.java:314)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$StatementThread.run(FailOnTimeout.java:74)
```

thanks

Comment: Guice 3 [allows `@Named` on methods](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/name/Named.java?name=3.0).  Try `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see if a conflicting Guice version is being used.

Comment: That was it, thank you for making me look there!

Answer (score 0):

Tavian Barnes' suggestion worked.